# Failing to Make a Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Sorry if my English is not the best.

`rails c`

```
>> Booking
=> Booking(id: integer, booking_date: date, start_time: time, end_time: time, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, room_id: integer, holiday_id: integer)
```

I want there to be no booking if it is already booked for a particular room at a particular date and time.

I tried--

```
def uniqueness_of_booking
    if(booking_date && start_time && end_time && room_detail)
    errors.add(:booking, "is not available") unless Booking.where("? >= start_time AND ? <= end_time AND ?== booking_date AND ?==room_detail",
     start_time, end_time ,booking_date , room_detail)

  end
end
```

**Bookingscontroller**

```
def create
    @booking = current_user.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user_id=current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @new_bookings.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Sorry, I am new here and links to a wiki would be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
errors.add(:booking, "is not available") unless Booking.where("? >= start_time AND ? <= end_time AND ?== booking_date AND ?==room_detail", start_time, end_time ,booking_date , room_detail)
```

will return an array of `ActiveRecord`. The boolean value will be `true` even if it is an empty array. Thus, you will probably need to use

```
errors.add(:booking, "is not available") unless Booking.where("? >= start_time AND ? <= end_time AND ?== booking_date AND ?==room_detail", start_time, end_time ,booking_date , room_detail).blank?
```

Comment: NoMethodError in BookingsController#create 
undefined method `room_detail' in bookingscontroller am i missing something?

Comment: In your `Booking` model, you just have column `room_id` but no `room_detail`. You have to match it.

Comment: by matching you mean rails g migration AddRoomDetailToBookings room_detail  ??

Comment: Yes if you need both `room_id` and `room_detail` columns in your model.